# Can't set a margin with AngularJS (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

My name is Fernando and this is my first topic in Stack Overflow. I was looking for my code error and I didn't get anything.

I created an application with AngularJS routing in which I added a container as I show in the example and I have added a span and a button. In that span and that button I added a margin, but does element are not obeying the code.

```css
div.mainHeader {
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
 background-image: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

div.mainHeader span {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: white;
}

div.mainHeader .md-fab {
 float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainHeader" ng-controller="linkController" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ linkHeader + 'international.png' }})'}">
    <span>International</span>
    <md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary" aria-label="Favorite">
        <md-icon class="material-icons">notifications_none</md-icon>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

> [>> CLICK HERE TO SEE THE APP <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPtNK.png)

// Fernando Pérez Lara (fernando.perez.lara@outlook.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but I think you are referring to the fact that the button does not obey the margin-bottom property?

This is because there is nothing below the element for the margin to 'push' against, so the margin just extends into empty space.

If so, you could try using CSS properties:

```
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

position:relative is a powerful CSS property as it allows elements to be moved freely whist retaining their original footprint on the page.

Comment: No problem, if you found this to be a correct answer please accept it so future readers will know the solution!